# Do all tautologies mean the same thing in Formal Semantics?

Tags: semantics

Since all tautologies share the same truth condition, that they're true no matter what, do all of them mean the same thing in Formal Semantics? Or does Formal Semantics analyze meaning beneath the sentence level as well?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to specify what you mean by "mean". If the "meaning" of a statement is its truth conditions, then yes, but even within formal semantics there are a lot of other types of "meaning" as well.

Comment: To answer your last question literally: yes, formal semantics does analyze meaning beneath the sentence level, because it is a compositional system: the meaning of a sentence is made up of the meaning of its constituents all the way down to individual nodes in your tree, so you can talk about meaning of constituents as well. But this is mostly orthogonal to what Draconis says.